# Are functions: $1$; $\cos(x)$; $\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I used the definition.

$1$; $\cos(x)$; $\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})$

$c_1\cdot1+c_2\cdot\cos(x)+c_3\cdot\cos^2(\frac{x}{2}) = 0$

I tried converting $\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})$ into something better: $\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}$

$c_1+c_2\cdot\cos(x)+c_3\cdot\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2} = 0$

$c_1+\cos(x)\cdot\left(c_2+c_3\cdot\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2\cos(x)}\right) = 0+0\cdot\cos(x)$

$c_1=0$

$c_2+c_3\cdot\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2\cos(x)}=0 \to c_2=-c_3\cdot\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2\cos(x)} \to \frac{c_2}{c_3}=\frac{-1-\cos(x)}{2\cos(x)}$

$c_2=-1-\cos(x)$ and $c_3=2\cos(x)$

There exist $c_i$-s outside of $c_i=0$ which can be solutions. So these functions are linearly dependent.

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: As you note, $2 \cos^2(x/2) = 1+\cos(x)$, which gives linear dependence.

Answer (score 2):

From $\cos^2(\tfrac{x}{2}) = \tfrac12+\tfrac12\cos(x)$ we get $$\tfrac12 + \tfrac12\cos(x) - \cos^2(\tfrac{x}{2}) = 0$$ that is, $c_1\cdot1+c_2\cdot\cos(x)+c_3\cdot\cos^2(\frac{x}{2}) = 0$ where $c_1=c_2=\tfrac12$ and $c_3=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Once you know that $$\cos^2 \frac{x}{2} = \frac{1 + \cos x}{2},$$ you already know that $$(1/2, 1/2, -1) \cdot (1, \cos x, \cos^2 \tfrac{x}{2}) = 0.$$